# Adding events to fullcalendar from an object VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying in vue to assign an event object to events but it doesn't show up to me, what am I doing wrong? Data displays correctly in the console but does not appear in the calendar.

```
import axios from "axios";
import "@fullcalendar/core/vdom";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue3";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

export default {
  name: "calendar",
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      allevents: [],
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: "dayGridMonth",
        dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
        events: this.allevents,
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("url_json")
      .then((response) => {
        this.listDataString = JSON.stringify(response.data, null, "\t");
        this.allevents = response.data.result.map(eventnew => ({title: eventnew.subject, start: eventnew.start.dateTime, end: eventnew.end.dateTime, allDay: 'true'}));
        console.log(this.allevents);
        return response;
      });
  },
};
```

Comment: Probably you're doing that after you've already passed all events into fullCalendar, so it's too late. Follow the fullCalendar documentation and set up a dynamic event feed instead. There are two possible approaches depending on your situation - an easy where you just supply a URL to get the events from, and a more flexible version where you specify a callback function to be executed whenever new events are needed - that's useful if you need to transform the data format or you need other options to set in the AJAX request or something.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for details of the two approaches.

Comment: the solution is to assign events in mounted

this.calendarOptions.events = response.data.result.map(eventnew => ({title: eventnew.subject, start: eventnew.start.dateTime, end: eventnew.end.dateTime, allDay: 'true'}));

Comment: If you found a solution that's great, but please add it as an Answer, below, not as a comment. Take the [tour] to understand how Stackoverflow works. You're allowed to answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 2):

the solution is to assign events in mounted `this.calendarOptions.events = response.data.result.map(eventnew => ({title: eventnew.subject, start: eventnew.start.dateTime, end: eventnew.end.dateTime, allDay: 'true'}));`